# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItem's property as cell text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a column bound like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status" SortMemberPath="Status.StatusName"                                         
    DisplayMemberPath="StatusName"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OrderStatuses}}"
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The DataGrid this column is member of is bound to a list of objects that each have a "`Status`" property which in turn has "`StatusName`" property.

With this binding I get these two errors as soon as I open any ComboBox for a cell:

> Cannot convert from type 'OrderStatus' to 'System.String'. Consider
> setting a converter on the binding.
>
> Value 'OrderStatus' cannot be assigned to property
> DataGridCell.CellContent (type String).

How do I get rid of this errors? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error today, the problem was that the property I was trying to bind was Null in some cases.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vmCatalogoRangosContractuales}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Nombre"
    SelectedValuePath="IdBAOngFMTRangosContractuales"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Restriccion.IdBAOngFMTRangosContractuales}"/>
```

In my case the property "Restriccion" was NULL. So basically the solution was to initialize an empty object in cases where that property was Null